# Размывается картинка в Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

У меня такая проблема: при увеличении блока `canvas`, у меня картинка становится все более размытая. Я поискал в интернете, и там советуют установить `imageSmoothingEnabled` в `false`, но это не сильно помогает. Подскажите, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно как вариант написать функцию, которая будет обновлять вложение картинки в канвас при каких-то событиях, в Вашем случае при увеличении блока